# i am new and trying to statisfy the consition nested if else

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS priceCheck; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION priceCheck() RETURNS int(5) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @breadth, breadth SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE @length, length SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE @height, height SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE @weigth, weigth SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE @ret int(32) DEFAULT 0; 

  SET @breadth = SELECT URR_BREADTH from order;
  SET @length = SELECT URR_LENGTH from order;
  SET @height = SELECT URR_HEIGHT from order;
  SET @weigth = SELECT URR_WEIGHT from order;
    BEGIN 
      IF (breadth != '' && height != '' && length != '' && weight != '' &&     breadth != '' && height!= 0.0 && length != 0.0 && weight != 0.0) THEN 
        if((length*breadth*height)/5000 >= weight) THEN
          IF(((urr_length*urr_breadth*urr_height)*1.2 >= 0.5) & ((urr_length*urr_breadth*urr_height)*1.2 <= 5) ) THEN
      SET ret = 30;
      RETURN ret;
      ELSE
      IF((urr_weight*1.2 > = 5)&(urr_weight*1.2<=12)) THEN
      SET ret = 20;
      RETURN ret;
  END IF; 
  IF ((weight*1.2 >=5)&(weight*1.2 <=12))
  SET ret = 50;

return ret;
      END IF;
END | 
DELIMITER ; 

[enter image description here][1]SELECT * from order;
```

i managed this much and not to execute please show me where did i missed
i managed this much and not to execute please show me where did i missed
i managed this much and not to execute please show me where did i missed
i managed this much and not to execute please show me where did i missed

Comment: Looks like you need the `fileinfo` PHP extension.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want from us other than telling you to install the `fileinfo` PHP extension - which the error message already does.

Answer (score 2):

To enable FileInfo extension, you need to edit your php.ini and change a single line.

1) Locate the line:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

2) Remove the starting comment:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

To find out where your php.ini is located, you can run the following command from a terminal:

```
php --ini
```

and search for "Loaded Configuration File".